# Identifying morphisms of affine $k$-scheme with solutions of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

[image: g]

Could you please explain the last equality? Could you briefly recall this identification/isomorphism with the zeros of polynomials?

Comment: Please take the time to retype your question using MathJax instead of just using a picture: see [Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26438/is-it-ok-to-take-a-picture-of-printed-formulaes-instead-of-typing-them-in-mathja) for policy details. Anyways, this is just unwinding the definitions: a morphism is determined by what it does to the generators $T_i$, and it must send $f_j$ to zero, so there you go.

Comment: @KReiser Sure I will do so, this is quite trivial question so I had in mind that I would delete the post afterwards; I was looking for a quick explanation.

Comment: @KReiser Ok thanks, so the last equality is only a bijection of set; i.e. isom in the category of sets right?

Comment: @KReiser Ok, it's clear thanks (I worked out the details on my own too);  so I will delete the post in a bit.

Comment: Posting and then deleting a question after you get helpful comments seems like a poor course of action to me - questions here should be of sufficient quality that they might help others later, in which case you should either leave it up to help others (and perhaps write your own solution) or have not asked it here in the first place. If you're looking for a more informal place to test the waters before necessarily posting a question, you may find [chat] to be helpful - I've found that quick reminder type questions can ofter get some purchase there.

Comment: @KReiser I'll keep that in mind and hence keep the post, retype my answer and question at a later time. Thanks for letting me know about the chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, let $R$ be a ring, $C$ an $R$-algebra, and $I$ an ideal of $R[t_1, ...  t_n]$ generated by polynomials $f_1, ... , f_r$.  The natural map

$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\textrm{$R$-alg}}(R[t_1,... , t_n], C) \rightarrow C^n \tag{1}$$

$$\phi \mapsto (\phi(t_1), ... , \phi(t_n))$$

is a bijection.

We can identify

$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\textrm{$R$-alg}}(R[t_1, ... , t_n]/I,C) $$

with the set of $\phi \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\textrm{$R$-alg}}(R[t_1,... , t_n],C)$ such that $\phi(f) = 0$ for all $f \in I$, or equivalently, such that $\phi(f_i) = 0$ for each $1 \leq i \leq r$.

Under the bijection (1), you can check that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\textrm{$R$-alg}}(R[t_1, ... , t_n]/I,C)$ identifies with the set

$$\{ c = (c_1, ... , c_n) \in C^n : f_i(c) = 0, 1 \leq i \leq r\}.$$